# Opening a Text File using PHP - Fixing the Format

Tags: php, format, wamp, fread

Basically, my text file contains this info:

```
WITH PARALLEL AND SERIAL


----- [System Info] -----------------------------------------------------------

Property                  Value
Machine Type              AT/AT COMPATIBLE
Infrared (IR) Supported   No
DMI System UUID           809EC223-DAD7DD11-A2F33085-A993FFAC
UUID                      23C29E80-D7DA-11DD-A2F3-3085A993FFAC
Disk Space                Disk C: 89 GB Available, 97 GB Total, 89 GB Free
Disk Space                Disk D: 355 GB Available, 368 GB Total, 355 GB Free
Disk Space                Disk F: 274 MB Available, 3837 MB Total, 274 MB Free
Physical Memory           1724 MB Total, 1173 MB Free
Memory Load               31%
Virtual Memory            3619 MB Total, 3184 MB Free
PageFile Name             \??\C:\pagefile.sys
PageFile Size             2046 MB
In use                    35 MB
Max used                  35 MB
Registry Size             3 MB (current), 120 MB (maximum)
Profile GUID              {bef54e40-80cb-11e2-a600-806d6172696f}
The system clock interval 15 ms



----- [Motherboard] ---------------------------------------

Property         Value
Manufacturer     ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
Model            P8H61-M LX R2.0
Version          Rev X.0x
Serial Number    120801441113185
North Bridge     Intel ID0100 Revision 09
South Bridge     Intel ID1C5C Revision 09
CPU              Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G645 @ 2.90GHz
Cpu Socket       
System Slots     4 PCI
Memory Summary   
Maximum Capacity 16384 MBytes
Memory Slots     2
Error Correction None
Warning!         Accuracy of DMI data cannot be guaranteed
```

However using this code in PHP to open it:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$myfile = fopen("baliwag_04162015.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("baliwag_04162015.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
}
?>
```

I get something like this:

WITH PARALLEL AND SERIAL ----- [System Info] ----------------------------------------------------------- Property Value Machine Type AT/AT COMPATIBLE Infrared (IR) Supported No DMI System UUID 809EC223-DAD7DD11-A2F33085-A993FFAC UUID 23C29E80-D7DA-11DD-A2F3-3085A993FFAC Disk Space Disk C: 89 GB Available, 97 GB Total, 89 GB Free Disk Space Disk D: 355 GB Available, 368 GB Total, 355 GB Free Disk Space Disk F: 274 MB Available, 3837 MB Total, 274 MB Free Physical Memory 1724 MB Total, 1173 MB Free Memory Load 31% Virtual Memory 3619 MB Total, 3184 MB Free PageFile Name \??\C:\pagefile.sys PageFile Size 2046 MB In use 35 MB Max used 35 MB Registry Size 3 MB (current), 120 MB (maximum) Profile GUID {bef54e40-80cb-11e2-a600-806d6172696f} The system clock interval 15 ms ----- [Motherboard] --------------------------------------- Property Value Manufacturer ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. Model P8H61-M LX R2.0 Version Rev X.0x Serial Number 120801441113185 North Bridge Intel ID0100 Revision 09 South Bridge Intel ID1C5C Revision 09 CPU Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G645 @ 2.90GHz Cpu Socket System Slots 4 PCI Memory Summary Maximum Capacity 16384 MBytes Memory Slots 2 Error Correction None Warning! Accuracy of DMI data cannot be guaranteed

What can I do so that I can achieve this output:

```
WITH PARALLEL AND SERIAL


----- [System Info] -----------------------------------------------------------

Property                  Value
Machine Type              AT/AT COMPATIBLE
Infrared (IR) Supported   No
DMI System UUID           809EC223-DAD7DD11-A2F33085-A993FFAC
UUID                      23C29E80-D7DA-11DD-A2F3-3085A993FFAC
Disk Space                Disk C: 89 GB Available, 97 GB Total, 89 GB Free
Disk Space                Disk D: 355 GB Available, 368 GB Total, 355 GB Free
Disk Space                Disk F: 274 MB Available, 3837 MB Total, 274 MB Free
Physical Memory           1724 MB Total, 1173 MB Free
Memory Load               31%
Virtual Memory            3619 MB Total, 3184 MB Free
PageFile Name             \??\C:\pagefile.sys
PageFile Size             2046 MB
In use                    35 MB
Max used                  35 MB
Registry Size             3 MB (current), 120 MB (maximum)
Profile GUID              {bef54e40-80cb-11e2-a600-806d6172696f}
The system clock interval 15 ms



----- [Motherboard] ---------------------------------------

Property         Value
Manufacturer     ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
Model            P8H61-M LX R2.0
Version          Rev X.0x
Serial Number    120801441113185
North Bridge     Intel ID0100 Revision 09
South Bridge     Intel ID1C5C Revision 09
CPU              Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G645 @ 2.90GHz
Cpu Socket       
System Slots     4 PCI
Memory Summary   
Maximum Capacity 16384 MBytes
Memory Slots     2
Error Correction None
Warning!         Accuracy of DMI data cannot be guaranteed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're outputting it in a browser, yeah that would be likely the case. If you want the formatting following inside the browser showing it, you'll need to add a `<pre>` pre format tag:

```
echo '<pre>';
echo fread($myfile,filesize("baliwag_04162015.txt"));
echo '</pre>';
```

Hint: You can also check out the `view source` and you'll see it there its okay.

Comment: @Dex sure no prob glad this helped